# Is this possible to make height of Html table th independent of others?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have problem that I want to make a html table in which height of one th equals to other th and td both in same tr. Is there any possibility to do that. I have tried it by changing the height of th but it changes the height of other th as well

```
 ------- --------
|       |        |
|  th   |        |
|       |        |
 -------    th   |
|       |        |
|  td   |        |
|       |        |
 ------- --------
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/8a2r1cmm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `rowspan="2"` please check below..

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>th</th>
  <th rowspan="2">th</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>td</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mt3gs5LL/1/)

Comment: Hi.. Thanx.. This is exactly what i needed